# Datetimepicker refuses to display date on page load

Tags: datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

So, I am using the datetimepicker by eonasdan. Everything appears to work fine except one field.

The field in question clears the input box that the date is in. Why does it not stay there?

I have tried the options `defaultDate` and `useCurrent`, but nothing seems to make a difference.

Here a sceenshot of my form:

[image: Screenshot Example]

Comment: Please show want you tried. Add the code (html + js) to your question instead of the screenshot. See here to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: post your html and JS